# Data variable on FLASH with PIC Microcontollers

Tags: mplab

I would want to store a data variable on FLASH with PIC microcontroller 16F726. I should not want to use 'const' keyword, as i would like this variable to be read/write. I am using the MPALB XC 8 compiler. Could anyone knowledgeable help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

In the header `<flash.h>`, you will find the functions `WriteBytesFlash()` and `ReadFlash()`. Look [here](http://www.edaboard.com/thread284934.html).

Here is an untested example :

```
#include <xc.h>
#include <flash.h>

void main()
{
  char input=2;
  WriteBytesFlash(0x1800,1,&input);

  char x;
  ReadFlash(0x1800, 1, &x);

  while(1);
}
```

I can't ensure you that it will work. If it does not, try to change the address...The program itself is stored in the flash memory and I don't know whether the program is protected or not.